# Can I run a relay just part time?

Tags: relays

I have been operating a potentially fast relay for a few days now. I only wish to run ~ 15 hrs. a day so I can shut off my laptop at night. I've been reading about Tor and relays for days now and haven't seen this addressed. On the average I begin at 6 am and shut down at 9 pm. does running a relay this way "fit in"?

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely say 'Yes' here, because your relay will help to improve the overall bandwidth of the Tor network. The Tor blog has an article which describes the [lifecycle of a new relay](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay). Your relay will probably always be in phase one. So it doesn't receive a Guard flag.

Another good approach ist to configure your laptop as a bridge. This helps users in censored countries to get access to the Internet. As far as I know it will help from the start and doesn't need the 'warm-up phase' like relays.

Comment: i have read about the life cycle of a relay. would i help more being a relay or a bridge at 15 hrs. a day?

Comment: But its bandwidth will never get tested, and so it will always be rated at 20 KB/sec, right? It ought to be a bridge, I think.